# Передача объекта между множеством контроллеров в AngularJs.

Tags: angularjs

Как передать текущий объект из одного контроллера в другой, затем тот же самый объект далее в третий, а потом вернуться назад во второй. Работаю с Ui Router.

```
;(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app")
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main");

        $stateProvider
            .state("main", {
                url: "/main",
                templateUrl: "main.html",
                controller: "MainController"
            })
            .state("control", {
                url: "/control",
                templateUrl: "control.html",
                controller: "ControlController",
            })
            .state("change", {
                url: "/change",
                templateUrl: "change.html",
                controller: "ChangeController",
            })
    })
```

})();

Пробовал через $stateParams, $state.go(), ничего не вышло, объект доходит с main до control, в change его уже не видно. Такое впечатление, что $stateParams хватает только на 1 переход, дальше он undefined.

Comment: а почему бы для этого не использовать [`service`](https://metanit.com/web/angular/3.1.php) и *внедрять* его туда где он необходим?

Comment: Я именно так и сделал, т.е. в сервисе создал ссылку на текущий объект  и в каждом элементе цепочки ссылался на него и обрабатывал его, и это отлично работает, НО есть ли способ сделать все эти манипуляции только с помощью UI-router?

Comment: а можно уточнить, чем вызвано желание решить задачу при помощи ui-router?

Comment: Здоровым любопытством ))) Я подумал, что если можно передать объект для обработки на один уровень вниз, то можно и на два и больше, но способа это сделать к сожалению не нашел.